# Getting splint to work with win32 integer suffixes

Tags: c, static-analysis, wdk, splint

Splint encounters a parse error for a system header file that uses the size-specifying suffixes that windows compilers seem to use. So splint can't parse a file containing an expression like `0xffui8` (where ui8 means unsigned integer of 8 bits). How can I configure splint to get around this?

Broader context: I am trying to get splint to work with WinDDK 7600.16385.1. File with example is `intsafe.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely lame solution I did was to copy the problematic files over to another directory, edit them to remove splint problems and then configure splint to use them before the ones in the WinDDK...\inc directory.